# Dereferencing addresses of one type as addresses of another

Tags: c++, pointers, types, casting, reference

This question applies to any coding language that allows users to manipulate pointers, but I am asking specifically in regards to C++.

Suppose we have two types that are of the same size, for example, suppose (long) and (int) are both 8 bytes in size. Let's declare a (long) and an (int):

```
long someLong = 10;
int someInt = 20;
```

Suppose the address of `someLong` and `someInt` are X and Y, respectively, and suppose that in hexadecimal, Y = X + 80. If I try to manually move X to Y and then dereference it, I do not get a value of 20 as I expect. Why is this?

```
cout << &someLong + 10    
cout << &someInt             // these two return the same starting address location

cout << *(&someLong + 10)    // dereferences an int as a long, but does not return 20!
```

Comment: When compiling for x64, the difference between int and long is somewhere between 0 and 4 bytes, depending on what compiler you use.

GCC uses the LP64 model, which means that ints are 32-bits but longs are 64-bits under 64-bit mode.

Comment: @yanivx Even if the pointers have the same size, I am not sure how portable such a code would be though. In particular, maybe the implementation choses to represent `someLong` and `someInt` in different ways.

Comment: @vsoftco implementation chooses the size as per the architecture

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's technically implementation dependent, so there's no guarantee.

On the other hand, in my experience using differently typed pointers to the same memory in practice tends to work the way you expect it to.

And this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long someLong = 10;
    int someInt = 20;

    cout << &someLong + 1 << '\n';
    cout << &someInt << '\n';

    cout << *(&someLong + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

[works for me](https://ideone.com/A3WNhk) such that it outputs 20.

To even hope to answer why it doesn't for you, we would have to see your actual code. And it would probably help to know what compiler you're using.

Comment: What is the platform used to compile the code is it windows?

Comment: Assuming the types have similar representations. Accessing `int*` via a `float*`, like `int* p = (int*)&some_float` won't work, even if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`